# Typing a list List<String> inside a reduce accumulator not compiling

Tags: java, types, reduce

I'm having trouble with typing the accumulator of a reduce operation, for two very distinct reasons.

**First**, I get from this article that when using the `(identity, accumulator)` signature, if the return type is different from the one inside the collection being reduced, it is necessary to have an explicit `combiner` to help the compiler. However, the return type is always made explicit by the identity we pass ! Why can't the compiler infer by itself that this also is the same ?

```
List<String> productNames =
    products.stream()
        .reduce(
            new ArrayList<>(), 
            (acc, elm) -> {
              List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(acc);
              newList.add(elm.getName());
              return newList; // Won't compile!
            });
```

**Second**, when I try to create a copy of my currently accumulated value, I have to explicitly pass the concrete type and not just the interface, as we usually do with Lists.

```
List<String> productNames =
    products.stream()
        .reduce(
            new ArrayList<>(),
            (acc, elm) -> {
              List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(acc);   // Won't compile! needs ArrayList<String>
              newList.add(elm.getName());
              return newList;
            },
            (list1, list2) -> {
              ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(list2);
              newList.addAll(list1);
              return newList;
            });
```

Comment: Please add compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

In this case to make reducing you should use method `<U> U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)` instead of `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`.

If we talk about the first signature, `U identity` and `BiFunction<U, ? super T, U>` return types have to be exactly the same `U` etc. ArrayList. And we can instantiate it as identity, but not List.

```
List<String> productNames =
    products.stream()
            .reduce(new ArrayList<>(),
                    (acc, elm) -> {
                        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(acc);
                        newList.add(elm.getName());
                        return newList; 
                    },
                    (list1, list2) -> { list1.addAll(list2); return list1;});
```

P.S. It is easier to reach this goal by collecting:

```
List<String> productNames =
    products.stream()
            .collect(ArrayList::new , 
                     (list, product) -> list.add(product.getName()), 
                     ArrayList::addAll);
```

or you can use map operation:

```
List<String> productNames =
    products.stream()
            .map(Product::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: thanks for providing a nice alternative implementation! except for the naming, you write list2, I think. you mean product, as list.getName() doesnt exist!

Comment: @Radioreve yes name list2 is confusing, i mean product, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Some colleague provided me with both answers in shortly I posted it so I'll try to explain it this way.

The **second** snippet does not compile because reduce is trying to infer the return based on what it is given. In this case, the identity is an explicit type, `ArrayList` therefore reduce expect this precise type to be returned, not a sibling. Hence, `List<String>` is too broad.

As for the **first** case, the generic type `<T>` inside reduce's type is the *same* as the one that is passed of inside the Stream. Hence, when we use a basic form with only an identity and an accumulator, Java explicitly expects T to be the same of the type inside the Stream. If we want to deviate from this, we have to pass in a third parameters, the combiner.

Answer (score 0):

For **first**. The signature is `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` so the identity must have same type as your stream element. You identity has `ArrayList<?>` type, your stream element

```java
(acc, elm) -> {
     List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(acc);
     newList.add(elm.getName());
```

is most likely of a different type.

For the **second** your accumulator function should be corrected too, and the combiner function can be simplified

```java
(list1, list2) -> {
    list2.addAll(list1);
    return list2;
}
```

Comment: do you mean its okay to mutate a list inside the combiner but not inside the accumulator?

Comment: both accumulator and combiner can mutate lists.